# Magento 1.9 installed but links do not work

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I am new to Magento. I have installed Magento1.9 on a wamp server (Apache Version: 2.4.9 & PHP Version: 5.5.12). I have run sample data on myadmin successfully.

Now the problem I am facing is I am not able to navigate on my home page. None of the links work. They all throw me *"The requested URL /magento/xxx.html was not found on this server"*.

Comment: Missing htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

You can test your server for compatibility by following these simple steps:

Download the [magento-check](http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip) file to your computer and unzip it.

Upload the extracted magento-check.php file to the Magento directory on your server
In your browser navigate to this page:

```
magento/magento-check.php
```

(Please insert the proper path to where ever you put the magento-check.php file.)

Answer (score 0):

Check rewrite mode of Apache is on or off.

In window path of httpd.conf is :- bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf

And Check #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so,
remove # from this and try to restart apache and check it.